# $f,g:[1,2]\to[1,2]$ such that $fg=gf$ but for no $x\in[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=g(x)=x$

Tags: fixed-points

Does there exist mappings $f,g:[1,2]\to[1,2]$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f$ but for no $x\in[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=g(x)=x?$

I am trying to figure out such mapping for quite a long time but failed. For all such pair I found a common fixed point.

Please help.

Comment: by $fg$ do you mean function composition?

Comment: @Alan Yes......

Comment: Are there any continuity assumptions?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Those share $f(1.5)=1.5$

Comment: f(x) = g(x) = 1-x for $x \notin \{ 1, 1.5 1\}$, $f(1) = g(1) = 1.5$, $f(1.5) = g(1.5) = 1$ might work. Note that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, the IVT implies this is impossible.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, your  $g(1.5)=1.5$ also

Comment: @JohannesKloos: No there is no continuity assumption

Comment: Just take any $f$ with $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x$ and then take $g = f$.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2-x$ for $x \neq 1.5$ and $g(1.5)=1.6$ for example, then $f \neq g$ for all $x$ but $f \circ g = g \circ f =g$

Comment: @N.Quy missing the condition that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$

Comment: @CSquared oh I forgot.

Comment: @CSquared Then I guess the statement should be Does there exist mapping $f,g \neq Id$... Otherwise, we just need to find examples for $f\neq g$ or $f \neq Id$. I mean the equation $f(x)=g(x)=x$ is easy to be failed.

Comment: @N.Quy idk. i thought it was clear. $f$ and $g$ can’t be equal to each other $\textit{ and }$ $f$ and $g$ can’t be the identity

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how arbitrary maps are allowed, there is plenty to choose from. One example would be (unless I have misunderstood the conditions) $$f(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases} 3 - x & x \not\in \{ 1, 1.5 \} \\ 1 & x = 1.5 \\ 1.5 & x = 1 \end{cases}:$$
First of all, since $f = g$, we obviously have $f \circ g = g \circ f$. Furthermore, suppose $f(x) = x$. If $x = 1$, $f(x) = 1.5 \neq 1 = x$; if $x = 1.5$, $f(x) = 1 \neq 1.5 = x$. So, $x \not\in \{ 1, 1.5 \}$, thus $f(x) = 1 - x$. As we have assumed $f(x) = x$, $x = 3-x$, i.e., $x=1.5$ - but we have just excluded that, contradiction! Thus, there is no $x \in [1,2]$ such that $f(x) = x$.