# Find $f,g:[1,2]\to[1,2]$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f=$constant but for no $x\in[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=g(x)=x$

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, fixed-points

Does there exist mappings $f,g:[1,2]\to[1,2]$ such that $f\circ g=g\circ f=$constant but for no $x\in[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=g(x)=x?$

Linked: [$f,g:[1,2]\to[1,2]$ such that $fg=gf$ but for no $x\in[1,2]$ we have $f(x)=g(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213454/f-g1-2-to1-2-such-that-fg-gf-but-for-no-x-in1-2-we-have-fx-gx)

Comment: This is completely different. Here $fg=gf=$constant which made it non-trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=c$ for some $c\in [1,2]$ and all $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore
$$f(c)=f(g(f(1))=c$$
and $$g(c)=g(f(g(1)))=c$$
So the pair of functions that you seek do not exist.